# Max count with related values in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dataset having some colors and counts with related dates.

```
+-----------+----------+-----+
|      color|      Date|count|
+-----------+----------+-----+
|        red|2014-05-26|    5|
|        red|2014-05-02|    1|
|        red|2015-04-02|    1|
|        red|2015-04-26|    1|
|        red|2015-09-26|    2|
|       blue|2014-05-26|    3|
|       blue|2014-06-02|    1|
|      brown|2014-07-31|    2|
|      green|2014-08-01|    2|
+-----------+----------+-----+
```

I want max count for each colors with related dates. I am using Spark 2.0.2 with Java 8.

when I used max function then it removed date column and when I put date into `groupBy` then it gives same table as input dataset.

```
df.groupBy(color).max("count").show();

+-----------+----------+
|color      |max(count)|
+-----------+----------+
|        red|         5|
|       blue|         3|
|      brown|         2|
|      green|         2|
+-----------+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
|color      |      date|max(count)|
+-----------+----------+----------+
|        red|2014-05-26|         5|
|       blue|2014-05-26|         3|
|      brown|2014-07-31|         2|
|      green|2014-08-01|         2|
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you want related column with max value so you can used `agg()` function for max value and `first()` for those related column.

```
df.groupBy(color).agg(first("date").alias(date),max("count")).show();   

+-----------+----------+----------+
|color      |      date|max(count)|
+-----------+----------+----------+
|        red|2014-05-26|         5|
|       blue|2014-05-26|         3|
|      brown|2014-07-31|         2|
|      green|2014-08-01|         2|
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is partially correct because `first` would return the first element of the group `date` generated by the grouping on `color`.

In the question, the `max(count)` is always at the first position for that particular color, hence the statement :

```
df.groupBy(color).agg(first("date").alias(date),max("count")).show();
```

returns correct results.

If your data was like this :

```
df.show
// red with highest count is at the bottom of the group
+-----+----------+-----+
|color|      date|count|
+-----+----------+-----+
|  red|2014-05-02|    1|
|  red|2015-04-02|    1|
|  red|2015-04-26|    1|
|  red|2015-09-26|    2|
|  red|2014-05-26|    5|
| blue|2014-05-26|    3|
| blue|2014-06-02|    1|
|brown|2014-07-31|    2|
|green|2014-08-01|    2|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

The query in question would return the first date in the group which corresponds to count 1 :

```
df.groupBy($"color").agg( first($"date").as("date") , max("count").as("count") ).show
+-----+----------+-----+
|color|      date|count|
+-----+----------+-----+
|brown|2014-07-31|    2|
|green|2014-08-01|    2|
| blue|2014-05-26|    3|
|  red|2014-05-02|    5|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions here :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expression.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy($"color").orderBy($"count".desc)

df.withColumn("rn", row_number over window).where($"rn" === 1 ).drop($"rn").show
+-----+----------+-----+
|color|      date|count|
+-----+----------+-----+
|brown|2014-07-31|    2|
|green|2014-08-01|    2|
| blue|2014-05-26|    3|
|  red|2014-05-26|    5|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: I need solution in java not in scala.

Comment: @dataScienctist This is just the method. We aren't here to write your code for you. You are supposed to take the answers as a reference and try to solve it further yourselves. Also, the Spark SQL API is quite similar for both Java and Scala. If you try, you'd realize.